# Updating form fiels when using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React Hooks and now trying it out in a form with many fields. I got stumped on how to update the form fields values.

So the scenario is I have a new user form. I have this at the top of my function:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({ id: 0, username: "", password: "" });
```

And then I have a handleChange function attached to each field (username, password) and what I'm currently doing is this:

```
function handleChange(event) {
    user[event.nativeEvent.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
```

Is it fine to directly edit the user field? I am under the impression that any edit should be done using the set function (setUser in this case). But if I put setUser in handleChange, every type it will re-render from what I understand. I was reading an article and that's what he was doing:

[image]

In this image, wouldn't the setName get called for every type of key and from what I understand, every call to a set triggers a re-render?

Or is this just how the way it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cause a re-render, you have to call setState. In your case, without directly editing the state value, you should update the whole user state to new using the old state.

```js
function handleChange(event) {
    user[event.nativeEvent.target.name] = event.target.value; // instead of doing this
    // do this
    let newUserObject = Object.assign({}, user, {
        [event.nativeEvent.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
    setUser(newUserObject)
}
```

To answer the second question, yes, the `setName` on change will cause a re-render every time the user types something into the input. But React used something called Virtual DOM and filter what on the DOM really got updated due to the effect of state change, and update only the required part on the DOM, which is very efficient.

So, it will cause a re-render but you don't have to worry about performance or state loss due to the re-render.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with your `NameForm` component, and your the management of the input state using the `useState` hook is doing what it is intended: which is to re-render `input` whenever there is a change in the values. This will ensure that the component's state will be updated as the user types on the input.

If you are worried about performance, you can do things like debouncing any subsequent side-effects, such as handling of http-requests that may be called when you are typing the input, or when you have submitted the form.